# PHP Prestashop extend form.tpl

Tags: php, prestashop

I would like to extend the form.tpl of Prestashop (1.6.1.1). Therefor I created the following path in my module folder:

> modules/mymodule/views/templates/admin/export/helpers/form/form.tpl

and

> modules/mymodule/views/templates/admin/helpers/form/form.tpl

form.tpl

```
{extends file="helpers/form/form.tpl"}

{block name="input"}
    {if $input.type == "test"}
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="test" class="form-control" placeholder="Te">
        </div>
    {/if}
{/block}
```

AdminExportController.php

```
public function renderForm() {
    $this->fields_form = array(
        'legend' => array(
            'title' => 'test'
        ),
        'input' => array(
            'type' => 'test'
        )
    );

    return parent::renderForm();
}
```

But nothing shows up in my form :/ Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Default you can place your form.tpl in the following folder:
{**module_dir**}/views/templates/admin/{**AdminController->tpl_folder**}/helpers/form/form.tpl.

The value for {AdminController->tpl_folder} can be retrieved in the class AdminController.php:

```
// Get the name of the folder containing the custom tpl files
$this->tpl_folder = Tools::toUnderscoreCase(substr($this->controller_name, 5)).'/';
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to locate here in ps 1.7.5.1:

```
/modules/YOUR_MODULE_NAME/views/templates/admin/_configure/helpers/form/form.tpl
```

Use this block name wth code:

```
{extends file="helpers/form/form.tpl"}

{block name="field"}
    {if $input.type == "test"}
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="test" class="form-control" placeholder="Te">
        </div>
    {/if}
{/block}
```

Comment: This looks pretty much identical to OPs existing code. Can you add some explanation to the answer as to why it might solve their problem?